# How to properly user Code Deploy (AWS) with laravel 5.*

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Ive been using Laravel and AWS for about a year now, i know there are people that deploy using code deploy (AWS) I have attempted doing it myself. But i want it to work with a load balancer and auto scaling group. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or give me a hand on this. I'm very grateful.

Comment: if you're using github: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy

Comment: Tell us do u succeeded with deploying your project source to individual ec2 instance using code deploy and are u following the basic configurations mentioned in code deploy apps pec http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html

Comment: Yea i can get one server going and successfully deploy to it. but i haven't figured out how to get it working with an autoscaling group.

Comment: You can select option auto scaling and select your auto scaling group name in your region

Comment: Use the scripts as an example for appspec.yml file. It helped me in my deployment. https://github.com/enzyme-ops/laravel-code-deploy-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working with AutoScaling Group, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html

For working with Load Balancer, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/elastic-load-balancing-integ.html